# mysql select distinct comma delimited values

Tags: mysql, group-by, row, distinct

i have a mysql table

```
id      cid    c_name       keywords
 1       28    Stutgart    BW,Mercedes,Porsche,Auto,Germany
 2       34    Roma        Sezar,A.S. Roma
 3       28    München     BMW,Oktober Fest,Auto,Germany
```

i need a query to show keywords from cid=28 but i want to see only 1 time a keyword, like (BW,Mercedes,Porsche,Auto,Bmw,Oktober Fest,Germany) 
i dont want to list 2 time a keyword, how can resolve this problem?

i have tried distinct but could not get what i want

Comment: You should normalize your data model. Storing comma separated values is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: thinking to normalize my db but it will take long time for me.. 98k entry :(

Comment: Shrug. 100k rows is *nothing* nowadays

Comment: with my mysql and php experience it will take long :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split it before adding it all up with DISTINCT.Of course,better is to normalize your data(no more than 1 value in a column)

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(keywords, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)) keyword
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(keywords, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(keywords)-n.digit
WHERE cid=28
```

[See it working](http://rextester.com/ZFND86695)

Comment: how can i print this query :(
thinking to normalize my db but it will take long time for me.. 98k entry :(

Comment: @Berdan I dont understand what you mean by print this query.

Comment: i used explode and split, i got what i want, but thank you.

Comment: @Mihai Can you please explain your query? It's great but I can't understand it properly. Please explain the use of each function in this query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a dynamic output then you can use the following query to get a distinct comma delimited values in a single record.

`Note: here doesn't matter how many values are in comma delimited row & it's fetched distinct record from a number of rows based on your condition`

```
$tag_list = DB::select('SELECT
                          TRIM(TRAILING "," FROM REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT keywords, ","),",,",",")) tag_list
                          FROM
                          test
                          WHERE id = 28');

$unique_tags = implode(',', array_unique(explode(",",$result[0]->search_tags)));
```

Comment: additional info:
keywords = your field name |
tag_list = query alias |
test = your table |
WHERE condition is optional