# MYSQL comma separated values of a column to unique comma separated values

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this. Dates column has duplicate values. I just need unique values.

```
id  Dates
1   2024-02-19,2024-02-19   
2   2024-02-19,2024-02-19,2024-02-26,2024-02-26,2024-02-26

I would like to achieve like below table

id  Dates
1   2024-02-19 
2   2024-02-19,2024-02-26
```

Are there any built-in methods on MYSQL to achieve this?

Comment: Show the code you tried.  Show the error.  This question needs to read like a question and not a request from an AI.

Comment: That being said , are you saying you have multiple values for that date and you just want one to be returned?  You can use LIMIT 1 to only get one result, that or you can use SELECT DISTINCT to select unique values

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546968/mysql-select-distinct-comma-delimited-values is one way.  and implemented [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/M2fjtniO)

Answer (score 0):

VOTED TO CLOSE as duplicate:

I take no credit for this as this answer is the source:
[mysql select distinct comma delimited values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546968/mysql-select-distinct-comma-delimited-values)

However, to show this implemented using your sample data and results:

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/M2fjtniO)

EXAMPLE:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 as ID, '2024-02-19,2024-02-19' as Dates UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'2024-02-19,2024-02-19,2024-02-26,2024-02-26,2024-02-26')
  
  SELECT id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(dates, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1)) val
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(Dates, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(dates)-n.digit
  Group by ID;
```

RESULTS:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id |          val          |
+----+-----------------------+
|  1 | 2024-02-19            |
|  2 | 2024-02-19,2024-02-26 |
+----+-----------------------+
```

with t is creating a common table expression ( a temporary table with your data)

Following the space is basically a copy and paste changing just the table name from the answer linked.  I added a group and ID since you want to show uniqueness per ID.